# What is the best term to indicate people's opinions seeing something as "not important" and "less important"? Please help

Tags: grammar, word-choice, terminology

I got trouble in determining any terms/noun phrases to describe the percentage of participants that answers "not important" and "less important" over several items which are distributed in my questionnaire.

What do you think about the following dictions to name the description above:

(1) Number of disapproval responses

(2) Disapproval rating

(3) Number of negative answers

Or, do you have any additional views regarding this naming system?

Comment: Disapproval is very different to unimportant.

Comment: So, could you give me recommendations in choosing the best words to describe "not important " and "less important" responses from participants in my study?

Comment: _Unimportant_ responses, _insignificant_ responses, _irrelevant_ responses, _trivial_ responses would be some of words/phrases you could consider using.

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh another question, could we use the word "rating" for the percentage of those responses? For example: The rating of trivial responses, or the rating of unimportant responses?

Comment: Literally speaking, percentage is the rate or number in each hundred. I don't think there is an alternative word for the same.

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh is rating the wrong choice, too? What is the difference between rate and rating? The conversation may go off topic, but I would really like to know about it, too. :((

Comment: I don't think I will be able to clarify your doubts regarding the word-usage, but I can say that __rating__ would be wrong here. If you think of using another word for percentage, I would say use __rate__. According to Google, rate has this one definition, _the amount of a charge or payment expressed as a percentage of another amount, or as a basis of calculation._

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh okay, or we also can use the term "amount", and "number", don't we? The phrases then might be, "the rate of trivial responses given by the participants" or the amount of insignificant responses by the participants." Am I true? :(( Thank you so much in advance. :((